# In complex variables, why is |z-1| < 5 an open disk centered at +1, where the boundary is a circle of radius 5?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

How can I justify this basic concept?

Use the definition of the modulus?

Write z = $e^{i\theta}$?

...and why is |z+1| < 5 ...centered at -1 and not +1?

Thanks,

Edit: it is always the basic plane geometry stuff, high school-level geometry / trigonometry that I have trouble with, and not so much with the later material of real / complex analysis.

Comment: But you always get the distance between two things by looking at their difference.

Comment: Very helpful and simple comment -- thank you, @Lubin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<5$. Thats the set of all points with distance less than five from the origin, so it's the open disc around zero of radius 5. By now going to $z+1$ you shift the entire space so that -1 gets mapped to zero while preserving relative distances. So now the disk is centred around -1.

Comment: Hi, @MatthiasKaul:  I went back to the definition of modulus and the equation of a circle.  So, |z-1| < 5 is the same as |x+iy - 1 | < 5, which is |(x-1) + iy| < 5, which, by definition of modulus, is $\sqrt{ (x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2)}$ < 5, but $(x-1)^2 + (y-0)^2 = 25$ is a circle, centered at (1,0), of radius 5.  Then we have that |z-1| < 5 is a disk centered at (1,0), of radius 5.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @MatthiasKaul.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how you would write a general equation of a disk in $\mathbb C$. Suppose it has centre $a\in \mathbb C$ and radius $r\in \mathbb R$. The one thing we know about points in this disk is that the distance between those points and the centre is less than to $r$. Let $z\in\mathbb C$ be an arbitrary point in the complex plane. Think of the vector from $a$ to $z$ on an argand diagram. You should see that this is equivalent to the complex number $z-a.$ Our condition for $z$ being in the disk is that this length is less than $r,$ thus $|z-a|<r$. In your case we have $a=-1,\quad z=5$ so we get $|z-(-1)|<5$ which is the same as $|z+1|<5.$

Comment: Thanks for your help, @DanRobertson.  I used the definition of modulus to convince myself that it is indeed a disk with the boundary being a circle of radius 5.